# Caching ASP.NET Web API with CacheCow

Tags: c#, caching, asp.net-web-api, cachecow

I am trying to implement caching using CacheCow. I have two problems:

1. In some cases I need to invalidate manually the cache of some resources.

   For example, I have a resource that it is called `purchase`, and other that is called `pointMovements`. They are not totally connected, but doing a post in `purchase`, implies some changes in `pointMovement`. Cachecow is not detecting these changes because I am not calling the API of `pointmovements`. So when I call the endpoint of `pointmovements`, the values are cached and I cannot get the new values.

   **To solve this, I need to invalidate that manually, how is that possible?**
2. There are some controllers that I don't want to cache. I am trying to use attributes for doing that but it is not working. I am following [this article](http://byterot.blogspot.com.es/2013/03/rest-asp-net-wep-api-0.4-new-features-breaking-change-cachecow-server.html) but the attributes are ignored.

   **How can I specify which controllers to cache?**

Comment: Hi, sorry for not getting back to you, do you still have the problem?

Answer (score 9):

I came across the same set of problems and found a solution for problem 2 (disable caching regardless of the default settings).

```
// This forces the server to not provide any caching by refreshing its cache table immediately (0 sec)
[HttpCacheRefreshPolicy(0)]
// This forces the client (browser) to not cache any data returned from the server (even if ETag is present) by setting the time-out to 0 and no-cache to true.
[HttpCacheControlPolicy(true, 0, true)]
public void MyController : ApiControler {... }
```

The attributes must be applied together for this to work. You can also control the caching at the action level by providing the same rules to each action.

I've still to figure out the solution for problem 1. but watch this space for updates.

**Update**
I have found a solution to problem 1.

1. Register the `CachingHandler` with your IoC container (in my case it's `IUnityContainer`)
2. Inject the `ICachingHandler` into your Web API controller.
3. To invalidate the resource, use `ICachingHandler.InvalidateResource(HttpRequestMessage)`

Please see a code example below. The solution has been tested.

```
public class Bootstrapper
{
    //...

    // Create a new caching handler and register it with the container.
    public void RegisterCache(HttpConfiguration config, IUnityContainer container)
    {
        var cachingHandler = new CachingHandler(config);
        // ...

        container.RegisterInstance<ICachingHandler>(cachingHandler);
    }
}

public class ResourceContoller : ApiController
{
    private ICachingHandler _cachingHandler;

    public ResourceContoller(ICachingHandler cachingHandler)
    {
        _cachingHandler = cachingHandler;       
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void DeleteResource(int resourceId)
    {
        // Do the delete
        // ...

        // Now invalidate the related resource cache entry      
        // Construct a http request message to the related resource
        // HINT: The "DefaultApi" may not be your api route name, so change this to match your route.
        // GOTCHA: The route matching mechanism is case sensitive, so be aware!
        var relatedResource = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, Url.Link("DefaultApi", new {controller = "linkedresource", action = "getlinkedresource", id: resourceId}));

        // Invalidate the resource with the caching handler.
        _cachingHandler.InvalidateResource(relatedResource);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for the late response.

As @Tri Q said, the way to do this is to use attributes which I have explained in this blog:

http://byterot.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/rest-asp-net-wep-api-0.4-new-features-breaking-change-cachecow-server.html

Answer (score 0):

I solved your #1 question using below code. Here I extend the `IRoutePatternProvider` interface. Remember, what you return in `GetRoutePattern` should match what you return in `GetLinkedRoutePatterns`. Only then the adding and removing will work. Try it out.

**Inside `Application_Start`**

```
CachingHandler cacheHandler = new CachingHandler(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        cacheHandler.RoutePatternProvider = new CacheRoutePatternProvider();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(cacheHandler);
```

**Custom Class**

```
public class CacheRoutePatternProvider : IRoutePatternProvider
{
    public string GetRoutePattern(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        string path = request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath;
        if (!path.EndsWith("/"))
            path += "/";

        return path;
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetLinkedRoutePatterns(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        string path = request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath;
        if(!path.EndsWith("/"))
            path += "/";

        int segmentIndex;
        // return each segment of the resource heirarchy
        while ((segmentIndex = path.LastIndexOf("/")) > 0)
        {
            path = path.Substring(0, segmentIndex);

            if(path.Contains("/api/"))
                yield return path + "/";
        }

        yield break;
    }
}
```